# Assign tooltips by element IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got 2 arrays.One is an array with button ids and the other is text

```
var btnArr = ["#b1", "#b2"];
var ttArr = ["Submit", "Clear"];
```

Is it possible to use jquery ui's tooltop together with the above arrays to identify the button and tooltip? e.g. hover on b1 -> tooltip shown as `Submit`

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/dwezvnfy/

```
var btnArr = ["#b1", "#b2"];
var ttArr = ["Submit", "Clear"];

$.each(btnArr, function (index) {
   $(btnArr[index]).attr('title', ttArr[index]);
});
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar he accepted your answer that doesn't mean  you down vote its not an wrong answer. if you can see example.

Comment: Boss, I gave the reason. Remove the `<i>` tag and I will remove the downvote. This is not good. I didn't say your answer is wrong! You have actually destroyed the rule of having `monospace` font for the codes.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i given different approach its not only for you if some one comes in future then they have choices

Comment: again, Did I say that your answer is wrong? It is good. But the way you have provided is wrong! Understand buddy! I have corrected and removed the downvote myself. Please learn from this mistake and don't do it again. Thanks!

Comment: k sorry my bad @PraveenKumar :D actually when i commited i didnt see your comment so i am sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82690/discussion-between-keval-bhatt-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Appreciate your effort bro. That's great :) +10

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can walk through like this:

```
$.each(btnArr, function (i, v) {
    $(v).tooltip({
        text: ttArr[i]
    });
});
```

Instead of creating two arrays, just give the element, a `title` attribute.

Comment: I just saw your edit.So you mean an array for the tool tip and a title attribute to all elements? So how would it refer the tooltip to the relevant title?

Comment: @Fergoso It just refer's the element's title attribute and gives the corresponding tooltip for that!

Comment: @Fergoso there is one more option may be it will help you see in my answer

Comment: I think Keval's answer is a better solution coz that could save me some time.